# "haven't gone to a restaurant"—is "gone" used correctly?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

I am wondering if the following is grammatical and idiomatic.

> I really love the restaurant but haven't **gone** in a while.

Is the word 'gone' used correctly here?

Comment: I'd probably use "been" instead, but it's not wrong to say gone.

Comment: As Showsni says. **There** is understood from the context.

Comment: Do you mean a specific one? Or in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are acceptable, in my experience as an American English speaker. However, this probably varies with regional dialect.

When talking about the act of going to restaurants in general, I generally use "gone," as in "I haven't gone to a restaurant in a while."

When talking about a *specific* restaurant, I generally use "been," as in "I haven't been to McDougal's in a while," or "I like Larby's, but I haven't been in some time."

However, neither one is particularly strict; it makes perfect sense to say "I haven't been to a restaurant in a while" as well as "I haven't gone to Ruddy Tubsday's in some time."

Comment: @Jasper Sure, I just thought it was funny.